# Redshift Correlated Subquery Internal Error

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So I have a table of bids in Amazon Redshift. Each bid has a description and a user who made the bid, and for each bid I want to know if a user made a bid with the same description in the last 5 days.

The query looks like this:

```
select b1.bid_id, case when
  exists(select b2.bid_id from dim_bid b2 WHERE b1.user_id = b2.user_id
                          and b2.bid_timestamp < b1.bid_timestamp and b2.bid_timestamp > b1.bid_timestamp - INTERVAL '5 day'
                          and b2.description = b1.description and b2.bid_timestamp > '2017-04-25') then 'good bid' else 'duplicate bid' END
  from dim_bid b1
  where b1.hidden
```

which doesn't work, giving the error: `this type of correlated subquery is not supported due to internal error`. However when I just add a "=True" at the end it works.

```
select b1.bid_id, case when
  exists(select b2.bid_id from dim_bid b2 WHERE b1.user_id = b2.user_id
                          and b2.bid_timestamp < b1.bid_timestamp and b2.bid_timestamp > b1.bid_timestamp - INTERVAL '5 day'
                          and b2.description = b1.description and b2.bid_timestamp > '2017-04-25') then 'good bid' else 'duplicate bid' END
  from dim_bid b1
  where b1.hidden = True
```

Is this just a bug, or is there some deep reason why the first one can't be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way to write the query uses `lag()`:

```
select b.*,
       (case when lag(b.bid_timestamp) over (partition by b.description order by b.timestamp) > b.bid_timestamp - interval '5 day'
             then 'good bid' else 'duplicate bid'
        end)
from dim_bid b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this first:

```
select b1.bid_id
from dim_bid b1
where b1.hidden
```

You will see that redshift will raise a different error(eg.  WHERE must be type boolean...). So argument of where must be a boolean in order for the query to run. So when you add '=True' then argument is boolean and query runs. And when the query has correlated subquery and there is an invalid operation in the query I have noticed that redshift raises correlated subquery error. This might be due to the fact that redshift does not support some of the correlated subqueries([correlated subqueries redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html)).

Answer (score 1):

The docs state the following:

> We recommend always checking Boolean values explicitly, as shown in the examples following. Implicit comparisons, such as WHERE flag or WHERE NOT flag might return unexpected results.

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Boolean_type.html

I do not think this is necessarily a bug. I would recommend always checking boolean values as `where b1.hidden is True`. I have seen this error quite a few times when using correlated subqueries, but I have always been able to fix it when explicitly checking the boolean values using `is true/false/unknown`.